# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' - Error Occurs while using Hilt

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

Added hilt dependencies:

**Build.gradle(project)**

```
def hilt_version = "2.38.1"
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
```

**Build.gradle(app)**

```
plugins {
 id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
 ....
 }

....

dependencies {
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1"
 .......
 }
```

I also have a global application class:

**MyApplication.kt**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application()
```

In my manifest:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".global.MyApplication"/>
```

Now, I create a module

**NetworkModule.kt**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NetworkModule {

}
```

I get error when I run my code:

****Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.**

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)**

When I remove these:
**@Module()** and **@InstallIn()**

The error goes away...

what could be the problem? The error shown to me is not informative at all.

Comment: Did you add the `kotlin-kapt` plugin in the `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes, its there:

id 'kotlin-kapt' @LucaPizzini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears there is an issue integrating Hilt while targeting version 31 (Android 12).

When I had:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

defaultConfig {
   minSdkVersion 21
   targetSdkVersion 31
}
```

The error appears...

but when I changed to:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
   minSdkVersion 21
   targetSdkVersion 30
}
```

It starts working, without that error..

Something wrong with integrating Hilt while targeting android 12 (likely)

Comment: But it is not a solution. We need to target API levels 31 and 32

Answer (score 3):

Keeping latest updated dagger hilt dependencies solved my problem.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

 //dagger 
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.40.5'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.40.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps to add the hilt dependencies as stated in the below site then an error will be resolved

https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup

Answer (score 0):

I Upgraded my project to Java 11 in the module gradle file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 11
    targetCompatibility 11
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "11"
}
```

And I updated to the latest gradle plugins

[image]

And made sure the project points to gradle jdk11
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to update android studio to Bumblebee's Android Studio version | 2021.1.1 RC 1

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

[gradle project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymTf6.png)

[gradle module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Fzp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Build for targetSdkVersion 31 works fine with version 2.42 (jvmTarget, sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility 1.8).
Versions before 2.42 failed to build successfully.